# 3D Point Source Attenuation Equation

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, attenuation

I was given the following equation to measure the intensity of a point source where $r_o$ is the reference and $r$ is the distance away.
[image]

I do not understand what to do if I make the coordinate origin $(0,0,0)$ ... the $r- r_0$ is just the length difference but $r_o = 0$ which does not make sense. Can someone clarify what is going on here?